# Extracting and transforming data in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have the following numpy vector

```
[[1, 3., 'John Doe', 'male', 'doc', '25'],
  ...,
 [9, 6., 'Jane Doe', 'female', 'p', '28']]
```

I need to extract relevant to my task data.

Being a novice in numpy and python in general, I would do it in the following manner:

```
data = np.array(
[[1, 3., 'John Doe', 'male', 'doc', 25],
 [9, 6., 'Jane Doe', 'female', 'p', 28]]
)

data_tr = np.zeros((data.shape[0], 3))
for i in range(0, data.shape[0]):
    data_tr[i][0] = data[i, 1]
    data_tr[i][1] = 0 if data[i, 3] == 'male' else 1
    data_tr[i][2] = data[i, 5]
```

And as a result I have the following:

```
[[  3.,   0.,  25.],
 [  6.,   1.,  28.]]
```

What I would like to know is if there is a more efficient or cleaner way to perform that.
Can anybody please help me with that?

Comment: A couple of comments - A `np.array` is a contiguous object, this means that every element has to be the same type so the result of `data` is already a list of strings since you can not marshall the 'male' and other strings to a numerica type. Better to use Lists.

Comment: Look at `data`.  It's a (2,6) array of strings, not mixed numbers and strings.  `data_tr` on the other hand is the default `float` dtype.  When assigning from `data` to `data_tr` `numpy` tries to convert the string to float.  In this case it works.  But if you get the columns wrong it may give an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach with `column-indexing` -

```
data_tr = np.zeros((data.shape[0], 3))
data_tr[:,[0,2]] = data[:, [1,5]]
data_tr[:,1] = data[:,3]=='male'
```

Note that the step : `data_tr[:,[0,2]] = data[:, [1,5]]` is working with copies off the respective columns. Those are not very efficient for assignments and extraction. So, you might want to do that in two separate steps, mostly for performance, like so -

```
data_tr[:,0] = data[:, 1]
data_tr[:,2] = data[:, 5]
```

Comment: re-reading the comment it seems that you actually only discuss the `algorithm` part.  Though you should point the user to Lists for the first bit. +1

Comment: @Chinny84 I don't know the source of input. Hence, I am in no position to condone or not condone on the inputs. As the answerer  I am starting from the given inputs and trying to get to the desired output. I am not sure that answers your concern, but I hope it does.

Comment: Hello, Divakar! Thanks for an answer, that sure is what I was looking for! While the main part is surely answered, I wanted to ask about best practices handling data like mine. As @Chinny84 pointed out (and as I suspected), I'm definetely using not the bes approach.

Comment: @DmitryVolkov Well as Chinny84 rightly mentioned that to work with such mixed dtype data, lists might be the best way. Or if you are working with int and strings only, keep it in two separate arrays. I am mostly speaking from performance point of view. For cleaner workflow, again lists might be the way to go.